# Split variable from comma into an ordered dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe like this, where the values are separated by comma.

```
# Events
# A,B,C
# C,D
# B,A
# D,B,A,E
# A,E,B
```

I would like to have the next data frame

```
# Event1  Event2  Event3  Event4  Event5
# A       B       C       NA      NA
# NA      NA      C       NA      NA
# A       B       NA      NA      NA
# A       B       NA      D       E
# A       B       NA      NA      E
```

I have tried with cSplit but I don't have the desired df. Is possible?

**NOTE: The values doesn't appear in the same possition as the variable Event in the second dataframe.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split strings by commas into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501700/split-strings-by-commas-into-columns)

Comment: Thanks @SamR but it doesn't. The difference is that my dataframe needs  to be ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Here is a base R solution.  split each row giving list `s` and create `cols` which contains the possible values.  Then iterate over `s` and convert that to a data frame.

Note that this does not hard code the column names and continues to work even if some column names are substrings of other column names.

```
s <- strsplit(DF$Events, ",")
cols <- unique(sort(unlist(s)))

data.frame(Event = t(sapply(s, function(x) ifelse(cols %in% x, cols, NA))))
```

giving:

```
  Event.1 Event.2 Event.3 Event.4 Event.5
1       A       B       C    <NA>    <NA>
2    <NA>    <NA>       C       D    <NA>
3       A       B    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
4       A       B    <NA>       D       E
5       A       B    <NA>    <NA>       E
```

**2)** This base R solution uses `strsplit` as above and then names the components since `stack` requires a named list and then invokes `stack`.  Then we expand that into a wide form using `tapply` and convert it to a data frame and fix up the names.

```
s <- strsplit(DF$Events, ",")
names(s) <- seq_along(s)
stk <- stack(s)

mat <- t(tapply(stk$values, stk, c))
colnames(mat) <- NULL
data.frame(Event = mat)
```

giving:

```
  Event.1 Event.2 Event.3 Event.4 Event.5
1       A       B       C    <NA>    <NA>
2    <NA>    <NA>       C       D    <NA>
3       A       B    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
4       A       B    <NA>       D       E
5       A       B    <NA>    <NA>       E
```

This could also be represented as an R 4.2+ pipeline:

```
DF |>
  with(setNames(Events, seq_along(Events))) |>
  strsplit(",") |>
  stack() |>
  with(tapply(values, data.frame(ind, values), c)) |>
  `colnames<-`(NULL) |>
  data.frame(Event = _)
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "Events
A,B,C
C,D
B,A
D,B,A,E
A,E,B"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. But if you see the df, All letters A must be in Event_1, B in Event_2, etc.

Comment: Have fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

Events = c("A,B,C", 'C,D', "B,A", "D,B,A,E", "A,E,B")

letters <- Events %>% str_split(",") %>% unlist() %>% unique()

df <- data.frame(Events)

df %>% 
  map2_dfc(.y = letters, ~ ifelse(str_detect(.x, .y), .y, NA)) %>% 
  set_names(nm = paste0("Events", 1:length(letters)))

#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   Events1 Events2 Events3 Events4 Events5
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 A       B       C       <NA>    <NA>   
#> 2 <NA>    <NA>    C       D       <NA>   
#> 3 A       B       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
#> 4 A       B       <NA>    D       E      
#> 5 A       B       <NA>    <NA>    E
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This `tidyverse` solution is easily the most economical in terms of amount of code used:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(Events) %>%
  # split the strings by the comma:
  mutate(Events = str_split(Events, ",")) %>%
  # unnest splitted values wider into columns:
  unnest_wider(Events, names_sep = "")
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Events1 Events2 Events3 Events4
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 A       B       C       NA     
2 C       D       NA      NA     
3 B       A       NA      NA     
4 D       B       A       E      
5 A       E       B       NA
```

Data:

```
Events = c("A,B,C", 'C,D', "B,A", "D,B,A,E", "A,E,B")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following base R code

```
> d <- t(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$Events, ","), 1:nrow(df)))))

> as.data.frame.matrix(`dim<-`(colnames(d)[ifelse(d > 0, d * col(d), NA)], dim(d)))
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
1    A    B    C <NA> <NA>
2 <NA> <NA>    C    D <NA>
3    A    B <NA> <NA> <NA>
4    A    B <NA>    D    E
5    A    B <NA> <NA>    E
```